# Make bootstrap table inside modal scrollable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make bootstrap table rendered inside modal scrollable with fixed header? Currently my modal-body is scrollable which makes table header disappear on scrolling.

[image]

**Code**

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <input type="text" id="market-search" onkeyup="marketSearch()" placeholder="Search for stock names..">
        <i class="fa fa-times" data-dismiss="modal"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
             <div class="card">
                 <div id="table" class="table-editable">
                     <table id="modal-table" class="sortable table table-bordered table-responsive-md table-hover">
                         <thead class="thead-dark">
                         <tr >
                             <th>Code</th>
                             <th>Name</th>
                             <th>LTP</th>
                             <th>Open Price</th>
                             <th>Previous Close</th>
                             <th>Low52</th>
                             <th>High52</th>
                             <th>Percentage (%)</th>
                             <th>Allocate</th>
                         </tr>
                         </thead>
                         <tbody id="allocate-table-body">
                         {% for stock in all_stocks %}
                         <tr id="stock_{{stock.code}}" class="stock-card" data-name="{{stock.name}}">
                             <td><a target="_blank" style="color:blue;" href="https://www.google.com/finance?q=NSE:{{ stock.code }}">{{stock.code}}</a></td>
                             <td>{{stock.name}}</td>
                             <td>{{stock.price}}</td>
                             <td>{{stock.open_price}}</td>
                             <td>{{stock.previous_close}}</td>
                             <td>{{stock.low52}}</td>
                             <td>{{stock.high52}}</td>
                             <td>
                                 <input type="number" id="input_{{stock.code}}" class="stockme"/>
                             </td>
                             <td>
                                 <a style="white-space:nowrap" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-success market-buy-button" onclick=insertRow("{{current_allocation}}","{{stock.code}}","{{stock.name|to_and}}","{{stock.price}}","{{stock.diff}}")>Allocate</a>
                             </td>
                         </tr>
                         {% endfor %}
                         </tbody>
                     </table>
                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.modal-dialog,
.modal-content {
    /* 100% of window height */
    height: 95%;
}

.modal-body {
    /* 100% = dialog height, 120px = header + footer */
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I would also want to reduce the row height.

Any leads here is really appreciable.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `#allocate-table-body { max-height: calc(100vh - 100px); overflow-y: auto; }`. If `100px` is not enough for what needs `height` outside of table body, increase it: `calc(100vh - 150px)`. Play with that `px` value until you find the right one for your case. Note: `100vh` means *"100% of viewport height"*.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
#allocate-table-body {
max-height : 300px;
overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question, you want just the body of the modal to be scrollable.
if that is the case then I think you should take a look at
[Bootstrap table](http://bootstrap-table.com)

[this](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#welcomes/modal-table.html) is an example of a table in a modal using [Bootstrap table](http://bootstrap-table.com)
https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#welcomes/modal-table.html

Hope it helps